# Can you express your answer to this riddle?

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> I’m a place where you can be
>   In a form, I’m one of three
>   Good or bad? Maybe
>   What is it that is me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you may be a:

> **STATE**

*I’m a place where you can be*

> A *state* in the geographical sense is a sub-division of a country - *a place where you can be*.

*In a form, I’m one of three*

> There are three basic *states of matter* - solid, liquid and gas (leaving aside plasma, etc. and anything more complex).

*Good or bad? Maybe*

> 'State' is a synonym for 'condition' and can be described in both positive and negative terms ("I left the project in a good state for someone else to carry it on." vs "Your room is a STATE, young man!").

As for the title:

> 'State' is also a synonym for 'express', meaning 'to put into words'